# Silverlight: Determine parent TreeViewItem?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a `TreeViewItem`. I'd like to get parent node of this item if any.

However `TreeViewItem.ParentTreeViewItem` property is internal, and thus not accessible.
There is no reason to hide this property from developers, however, someone very smart decided that way.

How do I proceed? Is there any workarounds (reflection on private members is not working in SL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an ugly, but working way:

```
static TreeViewItem GetParentItem(TreeViewItem item)
{
  for (var i = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item); i != null; i = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(i))
    if (i is TreeViewItem)
      return (TreeViewItem)i;

  return null;
}
```

So much wasted CPU cycles because of hidden readonly property :(