# Get FullPath in WPF treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf

If I create a WPF TreeView programmatically, for example:

```
// TreeView treeView; <- added in the designer
TreeViewItem rootNode = new TreeViewItem();
rootNode.Header = "RootNode"
treeView.Items.Add(rootNode);

TreeViewItem subNode1 = new TreeViewItem();
subNode1.Header = "SubNode1";
rootNode.Items.Add(subNode1);

TreeViewItem subNode2 = new TreeViewItem();
subNode2.Header = "SubNode2";
rootNode.Items.Add(subNode2);
```

However, I would like to get the path to a certain node in the treeview much like the `FullPath` property in the `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode` class. So the path for `subNode2` would be `RootNode//SubNode2`. How do I do this?

Edit: I am not looking for the manual solution, however I am wondering if there is an equivalent accessor like `FullPath` or if I'm going about using the WPF TreeView class in the wrong way. Eg. I've looked at `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` but they don't seem to provide the result I'm after.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look in my answer here:

[Silverlight: Determine parent TreeViewItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246159/silverlight-determine-parent-treeviewitem)

Determine path then is simple:

```
public string GetFullPath(TreeViewItem node) 
{
  if (node == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();

  var result = Convert.ToString(node.Header);

  for (var i = GetParentItem(node); i != null; i = GetParentItem(i))
    result = i.Header + "\\" + result;

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See below code.

So this function returns a stack in which top most item will be root and last item will be the immediate parent of element.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TreeViewItem rootNode = new TreeViewItem();
        rootNode.Header = "RootNode";
        treeView.Items.Add(rootNode); 

        TreeViewItem subNode1 = new TreeViewItem(); 
        subNode1.Header = "SubNode1"; 
        rootNode.Items.Add(subNode1); 

        TreeViewItem subNode2 = new TreeViewItem(); 
        subNode2.Header = "SubNode2"; 
        rootNode.Items.Add(subNode2);

        TreeViewItem subNode3 = new TreeViewItem();
        subNode3.Header = "SubNode3";
        subNode2.Items.Add(subNode3);  
    }

    public static Stack<TreeViewItem> GetNodeParent(UIElement element)
    {
        Stack<TreeViewItem> tempNodePath = new Stack<TreeViewItem>();
        // Walk up the element tree to the nearest tree view item. 
        TreeViewItem container = element as TreeViewItem;

        while ((element != null))
        {
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
            container = element as TreeViewItem;
            if(container!=null)
            tempNodePath.Push(container);
        }

        return tempNodePath;
    }

    private void treeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        Stack<TreeViewItem> path = GetNodeParent(e.NewValue as UIElement);
    }
}
```